# Why does FunctionalObjectProperty take an Object Property Expression, not a named property only?

Tags: owl, ontology

The functional object property axiom - here in functional syntax - has the form

```
FunctionalObjectProperty(P)
```

P is an Object Property Expression, which is one of:

- a named object property (PN). *Example: FunctionalObjectProperty(:hasBase)*
- the owl:topObjectProperty
- the owl:bottomObjectProperty
- an inverse property. *Example: FunctionalObjectProperty(ObjectInverseOf(:isBaseOf))*

The first is expected. What's the use of the three other variants? These seem to only increase the complexity of parsers, reasoners and APIs. (Yes, marginally.)
The last looks redundant since OWL has an "InverseFunctionalObjectProperty". And who declares top- or bottomObjectProperty as functional ?

I searched through ontologies like geneontology.org. So far, they use nothing else than a named property (PN) as parameter.
Anyway, OWL allows P here, and I may miss the forest for the trees. What is it good for ?

*Remark:The same can be asked for other unary property axioms like SymmetricObjectProperty.*

See: https://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/refcard

Answer (score 3):

This definition is used in OWL to define what the language syntax considers correct. However there can be some language constructs that are broadly used and other that are syntactically correct but have limited usage.

The definition of the FunctionalObjectProperty axiom allows one to state that an object property expression is functional — that is, that each individual can have at most one outgoing connection of the specified object property expression. [1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/)

The syntax definition of FunctionalObjectProperty is:

[Functional Object Properties:](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Functional_Object_Properties)

> FunctionalObjectProperty := 'FunctionalObjectProperty' '('
>   axiomAnnotations ObjectPropertyExpression ')'

This definition refers to the ObjectPropertyExpression which is defined as follows.

[Object Property Expression definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Definitions_of_OWL_2_Constructs)

> ObjectProperty := IRI
>
> ObjectPropertyExpression := ObjectProperty | InverseObjectProperty
>
> InverseObjectProperty := 'ObjectInverseOf' '(' ObjectProperty ')'

This basically mean that there are 2 ways to define an object property.
The first way is to directly define an IRI as an object property.
The second way is to indirectly define an object property as the inverse of an already defined object property.

The difference can be demonstrated in these examples:

> Example A: FunctionalObjectProperty(:isGoodFor)
>
> Example B: FunctionalObjectProperty(ObjectInverseOf(:isBaseOf))

The Example A uses an existing Object Property :isGoodFor while the Example B uses the inverse of the defined Object Property :isBaseOf without defining an IRI for it.

The syntax definition for ObjectPropertyExpression includes any Object Property IRI, since it does not exclude it. Therefore the TopObjectProperty and BottomObjectProperty are syntactically valid choices.
So the following are syntactically valid:

> FunctionalObjectProperty(owl:topObjectProperty)
>   FunctionalObjectProperty(owl:bottomObjectProperty)

However owl:topObjectProperty and owl:bottomObjectProperty have predefined semantics in OWL2. So while the above statements are syntactically correct, it would not be a good practice to use them.

[Definitions of TopObjectProperty and BottomObjectProperty](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Object_Properties)

Owl defines 2 built-in object properties with the IRIs owl:topObjectProperty and owl:bottomObjectProperty. And have  predefined semantics.
The object property with IRI owl:topObjectProperty connects all possible pairs of individuals.
The object property with IRI owl:bottomObjectProperty does not connect any pair of individuals.